# Splitting list into two separate positive and negative lists

Tags: c, split, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I wrote a function splitting one linked list into two, where passed list keeps *positive* numbers and returns *negative* numbers list.

```
struct elem {
    int val;
    struct elem *next;
};

struct elem *create(int val) {
    struct elem *temp;

    temp=(struct elem*) malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
    temp->val = val;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void addToEnd(struct elem* list, int nval) {
    struct elem *temp = list;
    struct elem *new_list = create(nval);
    if(temp == NULL) {
        list = new_list;
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new_list;
}


struct elem* split(struct elem** list) {
    struct elem* prev;
    struct elem* temp = *list;

    struct elem* positive = (struct elem*) malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
    struct elem* negative = (struct elem*) malloc(sizeof(struct elem));

    while(temp != NULL) {
        if(temp->val > 0) addToEnd(positive, temp->val);
        else if(temp->val < 0) addToEnd(negative, temp->val);
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free(prev);
    }

    *list = positive;
    return negative;
}
```

After using this function both of my lists contain *0* as a first value, no matter what values the passed list contains before using function.
How to fix this?

Comment: Kindle paste entire code

Comment: Because addToEnd does exactly that, adds values to the end. Since that's the first thing you do in split, it will only add elements to positive, not doing anything to the first element.

Comment: `addToEnd` doesn't work if the list is empty. It sets `list = new_list`, but `list` is local to `addToEnd`. Either declare the first parameter as `struct elem **list` or return the updated `list`.

Comment: I think it should work.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks, I decided addToEnd function to make new list in case the list is empty, but completely forgot that what I wrote was only working locally. Fixed that and it works as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `addToEnd` accepts the pointer to the head node in the list by value.

```
void addToEnd(struct elem* list, int nval) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer to the head node.

So assigning to the copy of the argument a new value in this if statement

```
if(temp == NULL) {
    list = new_list;
    return;
}
```

does not change the original pointer to the head node.

You need to pass the pointer to the head node by reference through a pointer to it.

Within the function `split` allocating memory like for example in these declarations

```
struct elem* positive = (struct elem*) malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
struct elem* negative = (struct elem*) malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
```

or in these statements

```
    if(temp->val > 0) addToEnd(positive, temp->val);
    else if(temp->val < 0) addToEnd(negative, temp->val)
```

does not make sense because nodes were already allocated. What you need is to move nodes with negative values in a new list.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct elem 
{
    int val;
    struct elem *next;
};

struct elem * create( int val ) 
{
    struct elem *temp = malloc( sizeof( *temp ) );
    
    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->val  = val;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    
    return temp;
}

int addToEnd( struct elem **list, int val ) 
{
    struct elem *temp = create( val );
    int success = temp != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        while ( *list ) list = &( *list )->next;
        
        *list = temp;
    }

    return success;
}

struct elem*  split( struct elem **list )
{
    struct elem *new_list = NULL;
    struct elem **current = &new_list;
    
    while ( *list )
    {
        if ( ( *list )->val < 0 )
        {
            *current = *list;
            *list = ( *list )->next;
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            list = &( *list )->next;
        }
    }
    
    return new_list;
}

void display( const struct elem *list )
{
    for ( ; list != NULL; list = list->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", list->val );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct elem *list = NULL;
    
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        addToEnd( &list, i % 2 != 0 ? -i : i );
    }
    
    display( list );
    
    struct elem *new_list = split( &list );
    
    display( list );
    display( new_list );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> -1 -> 2 -> -3 -> 4 -> -5 -> 6 -> -7 -> 8 -> -9 -> null
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> null
-1 -> -3 -> -5 -> -7 -> -9 -> null
```

Comment: You mean -- "I've allocated each node twice -- and it's still not working??"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I mean that neither new node shall be allocated in the function split.:)